# How do you programmatically resize and move windows with the Windows API?

Tags: windows, winapi

How do you programmatically resize and move windows with Windows API?

The scenario is: I want to vertically tile two windows (80%/20% width proportions).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For flicker-free, simultaneously positioning two (or more) windows, your best bet is to use  *[BeginDeferWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632672(VS.85).aspx)*, *[DeferWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632681(VS.85).aspx)* and *[EndDeferWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633440(VS.85).aspx)*. In your case, since you're moving two at the same time, this is your best bet.

Three older, simpler functions you might also consider are [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx), [MoveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx) and [AdjustWindowRectEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: `SetWindowPlacement` is yet another function that can do this.

Answer (score 15):

Use [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) in the Windows API.

Given a HWND, you can change the z-order, position (upper left), size, as well as numerous other flags (like showing or hiding, making it the active window or not, etc).

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for one of [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx), [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx) and [AdjustWindowRectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667(VS.85).aspx).

Can you be more specific about the scenario so that we can recomend the most appropriate API?

Comment: AdjustWindowRectEx doesn't move or resize windows.  It's for computing the windows size and position necessary to get the client area of the window to match a given rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

SetWindowPos or MoveWindow will accomplish this for you

Answer (score 3):

Look up **MoveWindow** in your SDK documentation.