# Using Ruby, Perl, or Python, how to "Move the window 'Firefox' to coordinate (0,0) on screen and resize it 1024 x 768"?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, winapi

Can it be moved by Window Title as well as exe name?

Other info on moving it in another language could be helpful.

Update: some Perl sample can be found in [Win32::GuiTest](http://p3rl.org/Win32::GuiTest) but there seems to be no resize or move functions.

Comment: I don't know applescript, but I think you would be able to do it with that. Try searching on google. To execute it w/ ruby, do `%x(osascript -e '...')`

Comment: hm... it is on Windows 7 and I was looking into doing it using Win32 calls

Comment: The whole world will hate you if you do this. Users expect their windows to stay where they put them. You will violate most "User Interaction style guides" if you move their application windows without asking them. What if I have firefox running at exactly the correct size to show my current page and then open your application in another tab. ** Don't do it **

Comment: what about for software testing purposes, to set a window as if it is on a screen of 1024 x 768, and even do some programmatic clicking or key press?  I think you are using quite strong word for something you cannot think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in Ruby using [win32-api](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/win32-api/):

```
# example.rb
require 'win32/api'
include Win32

FindWindow = API.new('FindWindow', 'PP', 'L', 'user32')
hWnd = FindWindow.call(nil, "firefox")
if (hWnd == 0)
  puts "firefox not found"
  exit 1
end

MoveWindow = API.new('MoveWindow', 'LIIIII', 'I', 'user32')
ret = MoveWindow.call(hWnd, 0, 0, 1024, 768, true)
if (ret == 0)
  puts "MoveWindow failed"
  exit 1
end

puts "success"
```

This only works if the window is called "firefox" *exactly* (not case-sensitive from when I tested). Since it is likely to be titled differently (e.g., "Google - Mozilla Firefox"), you'll probably want to use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) to enumerate through all windows and find the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[Win32::API](http://p3rl.org/Win32::API) and [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534.aspx). See also [*How do you programmatically resize and move windows with the Windows API?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692742/how-do-you-programmatically-resize-and-move-windows-with-the-windows-api).