# Moving the location and changing size of a external program

Tags: c#, .net, windows

By the term of external program, it refer to programs not developed by me.

I have 2 program that needs to be launch together, 1 of it is program developed by me, another is for instance, Window Media Player (just for example only).

These programs will be placed in a static position with no user interaction, so I need to configure their height width and their x/y coordinates. No issue for my own program, but for external program, will I be able to use window message to change their size as well as location.

I have never worked with window message before but I read up somewhere about sendMessage(), but I not sure of the command to move and resize.

My program is done in C#, and I hope to be able to do something like that

Comment: half way through this, i realized that by "program" you actually mean, "window".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MoveWindow  API

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

MoveWindow(ApplicationHandle, 600, 600, 600, 600, True);
```

Comment: So To set the position will be like what tenfour mention?

Comment: @C_Rance yes, exactly. Here's another thread that might be heplful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692742/how-do-you-programmatically-resize-and-move-windows-with-the-windows-api                          Edit: ps tenfours response, got posted just before mine... but I didn't read it before posting hence, I'm going to upvote him.

Comment: I tried this with the osk.exe and it did not work. By the way, unminimizing it with 
osk_wnd->PostMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, NULL);   //osk_wnd is a CWnd* variable that represents OSK main window. 
works great!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `HWND` (obtainable through `FindWindow` or `FindWindowEx`), you can use `SetWindowPos` / `MoveWindow`.