# How do I change another program's window's size?

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I change another program's -- let's say Skype's -- window's size, from my C# program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692742/how-do-you-programmatically-resize-and-move-windows-with-the-windows-api

Comment: If you break up this problem into two (1. How to affect another process' windows; 2. How to change any window's size) you should be able to find answers on Stack Overflow. PS: What if the foreign application has several windows open? Which one would you want to manipulate?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Where hWnd is the window you want to move):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

MoveWindow(ApplicationHandle, 600, 600, 600, 600, true);
```

If you don't know the window pointer, you can use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functionality.

Also worth a read is [MSDN SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Very similar to MoveWindow).

Comment: what is the `ApplicationHandle`? where this one came from?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the window handle of the other program, use Process.MainWindowHandle or [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Having this, you can [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) to move, resize, change the Z-order or the min/max/restore state of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Windows Api `SetWindowPos`

check this one out: [Using SetWindowPos in C# to move windows around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190423/using-setwindowpos-in-c-sharp-to-move-windows-around)

of course first you should know the handle of the window you want to resize, this can be done in many ways like getting the process by name then the MainWindow of that process or with `EnumWindow` or `FindWindow` APIs