# SetWindowPos not working on Form.Show()

Tags: c#, winapi

I am calling Form.Show() on a certain Form and do some stuff afterwards which
causes some updates on the Shown Form.

I want to move the this Window Form to another location with another Process during this time with SetWindowPos.
Sadly the calling of SetWindowPos does exactly nothing.
Probably because the is never idling?

Any Idea who to solve this Problem?

Thank you

Edit: some Code:

```
main.Show();
main.initBase(); //Takes 2-3 seconds
main.HideMainForm(); //Moves the form to (10000, 10000), to hide it (can't change that it's an old programm)
```

At the `main.Shown` event i have a call to another program which than calls 
    `SetWindowPos(pd.CurrentHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height, SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder);`

where r is the rectangle of the selected Display

I tried

```
EventHandler ev = new EventHandler((s, e) =>
{
    main.Close();
ev = new EventHandler((s2, e2) => { });
});

main.Shown += ev;       

main.ShowDialog();
main.Show();
```

which works fine but is just ugly code and i am trying to find a better solution.

Comment: It's successful the call to `SetWindowPos`?

Comment: Answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443502/56778 and similar questions indicate that it's possible. Show us some code. Perhaps you're missing something.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria yes it is.

Comment: @JimMischel added some Code maybe it helps

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities come to mind.

First, you say that at `main.Shown`, the external program calls `SetWindowPos` to move the window. And the code that shows the form takes 2 or 3 seconds to initialize and then moves the window off screen. Is it possible that the external program that calls `SetWindowPos` is executing *before* the call to `HideMainForm`?

What happens if you comment out the `HideMainForm`? Does the window get moved?

Second, you have:

```
SetWindowPos(
    pd.CurrentHandle, 
    HWND_TOPMOST,
    r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height,
    SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder);
```

It might be that the `DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder` flag is interfering with the `HWND_TOPMOST` request, and the function is failing. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> A window can be made a topmost window either by setting the hWndInsertAfter parameter to HWND_TOPMOST and ensuring that the SWP_NOZORDER flag is not set, or by setting a window's position in the Z order so that it is above any existing topmost windows. When a non-topmost window is made topmost, its owned windows are also made topmost. Its owners, however, are not changed.

Granted, that doesn't say anything about the `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag, but in the general case the owner's Z order will change if something is placed above it. So if you request that flag and the function can't ensure it, the function might fail.

You need to check the return value of `SetWindowPos`:

```
bool success = SetWindowPos(...);
if (!success)
{
    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    // the err value will give you information about why it failed.
}
```

For that to work, your `DllImport` must have `SetLastError=true`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Form.showDialog()?

It happens if so. Use Form.show() instead.