# Start a program on different screen

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, setwindowpos

I've already checked out:

> [SetWindowPos not working on Form.Show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615676/setwindowpos-not-working-on-form-show)
>
> [Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

However, none of these solutions seem to work for me. I want to open an external program on a different monitor.

This is my current code:

```
 public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
 public const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
 public const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);


 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


 Process application = new Process();
 application.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 application.StartInfo.FileName = ".......";
 if (application.Start())
 {
     Rectangle monitor = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds; // for monitor no 2

     SetWindowPos(
         application.MainWindowHandle,
         IntPtr.Zero,
         monitor.Left,
         monitor.Top,
         monitor.Width,
         monitor.Height,
         SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                
     UpdateWindow(application.MainWindowHandle); // tried even with application.Handle
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need `UpdateWindow`, calling `SetWindowPos` is probably enough. You just need to make sure that the window handle is created *(because the process is being started)*. Simply add the following line before calling `SetWindowPos`:

```
application.WaitForInputIdle();
```

If `WaitForInputIdle()` doesn't work for you, you might try something like:

```
while (application.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

The following code works fine for me:

```
Process application = new Process();
application.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
application.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
if (application.Start())
{
    application.WaitForInputIdle();
    /* Optional
    while (application.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    } */

    Rectangle monitor = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds; // for monitor no 2

    SetWindowPos(
        application.MainWindowHandle,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        monitor.Left,
        monitor.Top,
        monitor.Width,
        monitor.Height,
        SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

Note that this will only set the position of the window, not its size though. If you want the size to be changed as well, you'll need to remove the `SWP_NOSIZE` flag.