# How can I set the size of an Excel window?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a wpf window which should be opened beside an Excel window. Excel is opened and handled with Interop.Excel.
In my Window i have a method, which should set the size of the excel window.

```
private void SetLayout()
        {
            Top = 0;
            Left = 0;
            Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
            ((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.Height =
                SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
            ((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.Left = Width;
            ((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width;
        }
```

In my Viewmodel I have a Manager which gives back the open Excel App (Office.Interop.Excel.Application).
I can set the Height,Top,.. of my wpf window and it works fine, but not on the Excel window. **How can i set the size of the Excel window beside my wpf window so that the two fill the complete screen together?**

Edit:

I tried this, but it is also not working:

```
((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;
((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.ActiveWindow.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
((ConfiguratorWindowViewModel) DataContext).Manager.App.ActiveWindow.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - Width;
```

Both sets the Height to a different value but not to the correct one, when i hardcode it like `.Height=800;` it's also not working.

Unfortunately i can't post images to show you how it Looks and it should look like.

Edit:

The question is not the same as this one ([How do I change another program's window's size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size)). I don't want to change the size of ah "foreign" application.

Answer (score 6):

Lets say you have excel application stored in a variable called App. Then you can do something like this:

```
App.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;
App.ActiveWindow.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
App.ActiveWindow.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

Screen class is used to get the resolution of your primary screen.

You could probably also just maximize the window:

```
 App.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
```

Comment: For some reasons its not working. It dont put the correct value into App.ActiveWindow.Height and .Width there are completely different values.

Comment: What is the range or what values to be passed to the App.ActiveWindow.Height and .Width. Documentation for these is not very clear, thanks