# Change Window Style of other process's window in .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way to change the window Style/Location/Size for a window that is running in another process?

We have an integration that requires a desktop app be running, i'd like to programmatically change it from being fullscreen to minimized or "normal" state and placed in the corner of the app.

Comment: checkout this site sounds like this may be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size

Comment: Somebody mis-spelled SetWindowPos() in that Q+A.  What you need.