# Which browser does Process.Start use

Tags: c#, .net, browser

My default browser is google Chrome
in c#, I have process.start("some url e.g. **.html") 
but it stills opens up in IE. 
I wonder how can we know/control which browser process.start will use?

updated:
sorry I miss one point here,   on my pc .html file is associated with Chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108728/c-sharp-process-start-chrome-exe-declare-height

Comment: It looks like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503909/how-can-i-launch-a-url-in-the-users-default-browser-from-my-application) might have a good answer to your question.

Comment: if you execute `ftype htmlfile` in the command prompt, what does it give you?

Answer (score 0):

Your default browser is not the same as your default .html file reader, if the html file is Process.Start will potentially open it with a different program.

```
//opens your default browser
Process.Start("www.google.com"); 
//opens in IE if that's your configured default program for html files.
Process.Start(@"C:\myFile.html");
```