# Change external app window size from Electron code

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, winapi, electron

I have an ElectronJS app with 2 buttons: "FF" and "IE", when I click on them, it opens the related browser via [Node Childprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) function.

Now, I want, somehow, to resize the opened browser window to be 600*600px (for instance).

I tried to looks if Electron has some functionality to do that but I can't find nothing, I also tried to understand if I can do it thru windows CLI but also didn't find anything.

Do anyone have some idea how to perform this such behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answers in [How do I change another program's window's size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size) should give you some ideas, you can call Win32 APIs in Electron using `node-ffi` or from a native Node module.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, with `node-ffi` i assume you meant to call some DLL file that make the resizing/reposition, right?

Comment: @ShlomiSasson Correct, the `MoveWindow` function for example lives in `User32.dll`, so you could use `node-ffi` to load that dll and then call the function.

Comment: Sounds good, ill try soon. BTW, if i have the PID of the browser window, is it enough to get the window handler inside the DLL?