# Is it possible to set another application's window's maximum width from its window handle?

Tags: c#, windows, window-handles

I currently have an `IntPtr` of a window handle, and I tried getting its `Window` using [HwndSource.FromHwnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource(v=vs.110).aspx) but it returns `null`. If the `Window` element was retrieved, it would have been possible to set its `MaxWidth` attribute.

Are there other ways to set the maximum width just from having a window handle of an external application?

EDIT:
Trying to see if [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm)'s approach works. The question's tagged C# but this could be worth a shot using a C++ custom DLL:

```
bool InitializeMaxWidthHook(int threadID, HWND destination)
{
    if (g_appInstance == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    SetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HCBT_MINMAX", destination);

    hookMaxWidth = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)MinMaxHookCallback, g_appInstance, threadID);
    return hookMaxWidth != NULL;
}

void UninitializeMaxWidthHook()
{
    if (hookMaxWidth != NULL)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookMaxWidth);
    hookMaxWidth = NULL;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK MinMaxHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        UINT msg = 0;

        if (code == HCBT_MINMAX)
            msg = RegisterWindowMessage("WILSON_HOOK_HCBT_MINMAX");

        HWND dstWnd = (HWND)GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HCBT_MINMAX");

        if (msg != 0)
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookMaxWidth, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

I'll update the question again after tinkering with this.

Comment: window not have any `MaxWidth` attributes. window procedure handle [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626(v=vs.85).aspx) message and return `ptMaxSize` in [`MINMAXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632605(v=vs.85).aspx) - so only way control window procedure

Comment: possible way do this - set  [`WH_CALLWNDPROCRET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644976(v=vs.85).aspx) - implement CallWndRetProc callback function and change `MINMAXINFO` structure

Comment: Another approach would be to monitor (poll) window size and [resize it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443502/1997232) when it's too big.

Comment: RbMm's solutions cannot work, it requires injecting code into the process that owns the window and that can't be C# code.  Using the System.Windows.Automation namespace or SetWinEventHook() to monitor for size changes is about as practical as it gets.

Comment: @Hans Yeah, the tag's actually for C#. I'll definitely try your approach after checking the custom DLL one.

Comment: but `HCBT_MINMAX` is related to [`CBTProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx) callback  - change `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` to `WH_CBT`. also may be you need handle `HCBT_MOVESIZE` - `lParam Specifies a long pointer to a RECT structure containing the coordinates of the window. By changing the values in the structure, a CBTProc hook procedure can set the final coordinates of the window`

Comment: @RbMm Haha I should have checked this thread an hour ago. I just found out about ```WH_CBT``` from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_cbthook). I'll check out ```HCBT_MOVESIZE``` after this. It's really hard having to work on WPF without any prior knowledge. I just came from Android development and had to be assigned ASAP to a Windows project. Ahh the highs and lows of software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with isn't purely C#, so this doesn't perfectly fit the question tags, but I'll post it anyway.

I created a third-party DLL with initialization functions for `WndProc` hook to listen to `GETMINMAXINFO` (I removed some parts of the code for privacy, but this is the one for `GETMINMAXINFO`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE g_appInstance = NULL;
typedef void (CALLBACK *HookProc)(int code, WPARAM w, LPARAM l);

HHOOK hookWndProc = NULL;
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

bool InitializeWndProcHook(int threadID, HWND destination)
{
    if (g_appInstance == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    SetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_WND_PROC", destination);

    hookWndProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)WndProcHookCallback, g_appInstance, threadID);
    return hookWndProc != NULL;
}

void UninitializeWndProcHook()
{
    if (hookWndProc != NULL)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookWndProc);
    hookWndProc = NULL;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcHookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        UINT msg = 0;

        WPARAM newWPARAM;
        LPARAM newLPARAM;
        if (code == HC_ACTION)
        {
            CWPSTRUCT *wndProc = (CWPSTRUCT *)lparam;           
            if (shouldSendMessageOnWindow(wndProc->hwnd))
            {
                // if the message is from other process, the value of wparam is null
                UINT wndProcMessage = wndProc->message;
                if (wndProcMessage == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
                {
                    newWPARAM = (WPARAM)wndProc->hwnd;
                    newLPARAM = (LPARAM)wndProc->lParam;
                    msg = RegisterWindowMessage("WILSON_HOOK_HC_ACTION_WND_PROC_WM_GETMINMAXINFO");
                }
            }
        }

        if (msg != 0)
        {
            HWND dstWnd = (HWND)GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_WND_PROC");
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg, newWPARAM, newLPARAM);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookWndProc, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

I then initialized this hook in my C# code and waited for the `MINMAX` message then set the info to the size I wanted.

```
private struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

private struct MINMAXINFO
{
    public POINT ptReserved;
    public POINT ptMaxSize;
    public POINT ptMaxPosition;
    public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
    public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
}

/**Other Code**/

MINMAXINFO* minMaxInfo = (MINMAXINFO*) lParam;

int currentMaxSize = minMaxInfo->ptMaxSize.x;
Debug.WriteLine("Updated max" + currentMaxSize);

minMaxInfo->ptMaxSize.x = screenWidth; 
minMaxInfo->ptMaxSize.y = screenHeight;

User32.SetWindowPos(wParam, User32.SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, User32.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_DRAWFRAME | User32.SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);

/**Other Code**/
```

**This worked for some applications (I think for Win32 apps only). Some applications such as Metro Apps and possibly Java applets can't be accessed.**

But for now, this is probably good for starters.

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) for guiding me to this answer.