# Windows / Open application within new process and resize

Tags: windows

I have a windows embedded PC that has a custom 3rd party shell developed that runs in a full-screen mode. Unfortunately, it doesn't work correctly with certain applications that are larger than the resolution of the device and pushes the bottom off the screen of certain applications. I don't have access to the source code to change the any of the applications that break.

I am trying to work out if its possible to create a new full screen or windows form application that will open another application within the new process and resize it to the correct resolution. The application that I am trying to open inside a new process is a full-screen application and the size is not changeable.

I have seen that in C# you can embed another application within the form, however, is it also possible to resize a full-screen application within the form?

Comment: have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size)? why do i feel yours might be a duplicate..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change another program's window's size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443502/how-do-i-change-another-programs-windows-size)