# javascript : window.open

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html

I am working in vb.net 2005. I am in a position to start a new browser with process.start().
Now I have to open that browser in a specific size(say height:300 width:500)

```
Process.Start("firefox.exe", "abc.html")
```

and I have written this following code on load of abc.html

```
var myRef = window.open('abc.html','','left=20,top=20,width=300,height=500');
```

but it does not resize.

If I add 1 button on this page and click on it (by writing same code on its click event), a new window with expected size opens.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Thanx.

Comment: Could you paste the code for `abc.html`?

Comment: <html   >
  <head>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var myRef = window.open('./abc.html',' ','left=20,top=20,width=300,height=500');
  </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="red"></body>
</html>

Comment: You should be using [`resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo) to resize the window, not opening it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't [let pages resize the window by default](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541).  Also note, if you already have Firefox running then browser preferences will dictate whether you get a new window or a tab.  You can force a separate instance of Firefox by using the `-no-remote` command line flag, but then you won't be able to use the default profile (only one Firefox instance per profile).

My questions for you are:

- Why are you launching Firefox from another executable at all instead of just having users click on a link and have it open in their default browser?
- If you do need to launch Firefox from an executable, why spend all this effort overriding the user's preferences and settings?
- If you' re launching from an executable and are keen to annoy your users whatever the cost, why not just find and resize the Firefox window [using the normal Windows APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/692742/8655)?