# Is there a function to resize terminal?

Tags: windows, go, cmd

I searched around a lot but found just how to get terminal size, but not how to resize it.

Are there any solutions?

I tried with `\e[8;50;100t` but it doesn't work on windows.

Comment: are you trying to resize the emulator's window?

Comment: I'm trying to resize CMD window

Comment: Don't use `cmd`, use Windows Terminal. `cmd` is the *old* terminal infrastructure that doesn't understand terminal sequences. It's been replaced by Windows Terminal and a rewritten infrastructure in Windows 10, the only supported version

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Windows API to do that. Here a Stack-Overflow answer that gives you the correct API calls needed to do that: [How do you programmatically resize and move windows with the Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692742/how-do-you-programmatically-resize-and-move-windows-with-the-windows-api)

From Go you can call the Windows API either using CGO or using `syscall`. Here an article that uses `syscall` which is easier to get started: https://medium.com/@justen.walker/breaking-all-the-rules-using-go-to-call-windows-api-2cbfd8c79724

Note that you should always protect a file using Windows specific commands with a build flag. This won't work for other OSs. If you need this to work for other OSs, too, you need to implement different versions for the OSs you want to support.